# iOS Facebook SDK 3.0 Login not redirecting to origin app

Tags: ios, facebook-login

I recently updated my ios app to facebook sdk 3.0.

I did everything like describes here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

When I hit the Login with Facebook button everything works fine. The FB app is coming up, asks me for permissions BUT -> it doesn't redirect to come back to my app. It just stays with the FB app.

With the old SDK everything worked fine. Is it that the new SDK is not working with iOS 5?

I don't even know how to debug this...

Thanks for any kind of help!

UPDATE

It has something to do with my URL Schemes. Seems like ios SDK 3 doesn't like characters in the id. My former Scheme entry was fb0000000new where as the 0 are replaced by the app id. When I change that to just fb0000000 it works.

Would be good to have a link in the documentation though!

Answer (score -1):

just try this its worked out for me

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/28/facebook-sdk-posting-to-user-news-feed/

Comment: well the thing is that I had it working with the previous SDK version. Since I included SDK v3.0 is stopped working and I did everything like Facebook explains in their guide